# what is intra-farm latency in sharepoint farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

What is the intra-farm latency in SharePoint farms and where it is used? here i want to know about this concept latency in a SharePoint farm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the round trip time typically measured with ping, psping, hrping, or other tools. RTT for SharePoint Server to SharePoint Server, or SharePoint Server to SQL Server must be 1ms 99.9% on average over 10 minutes in order for the farm to be withing supported boundaries.

While not your question, the information about [stretched farms](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748824.aspx#CfgStretchedFarm) describes this as well.